# Redirect all visitors based on url parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, dns

i would like to redirect user based on the parameter in url?

https://example.com/redirect_handler?param=foo&url=http//currentuserwebsite.com

https://example.com/redirect_handler?param=foo&url=
so user will be redirected to exmple.com first and based on url param the user will be redirected to url param (to user admin).

Is is possible to do?

Comment: Yes you can do this. You read the parameter from the URL and then use it in a redirect.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber will it be possible to show me a simple example , i am new to this ..please ..do i have to use $_GET('url')? but how can know when user is hitting my page

Comment: something like `<?php echo $_GET['url'];` to echo out the URL param. Use that for your redirect.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber okay thanks .let me have a try

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you should try:

So let's Say the link is 
https://example.com/redirect_handler?param=foo&url=http//currentuserwebsite.com

What you need to do is the following: 
At the top of the php file write the following code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['url'])){ //check if the URL parameter is there
$url = $_GET['url']; //declare $url as the parm 
Header('Location:'.$url); //note if you are using WordPress use wp_redirect Function
} //end if
?>
```